# Trouble with coupling VTK with Java

Tags: java, c++, vtk

I've been mostly familiar with Java (I'm using a Windows laptop, just an fyi), so when I was asked to do stuff with VTK (which, to my understanding, is created mostly using C++, or at the very least a coworker gave me a VTK class, vtkLandmarkTransform, in C++; if there's a repository that includes vtkLandmarkTransform in java as well as all the VTK classes that are imported into vtkLandmarkTransform, that would be great), I tried coupling VTK with Java. I've been mostly using these two sites:

> [http://web.archive.org/web/20100817005723/http://www.spinet.pl/~wilku/vtk-howto/](http://web.archive.org/web/20100817005723/http://www.spinet.pl/%7Ewilku/vtk-howto/)
> https://www.particleincell.com/2011/vtk-java-visualization/

I've gotten as far as the second paragraph of Step 3. in the first link which corresponds to Step 7. in the second link (building the INSTALL file). From my understanding, the result of this is supposed to be a bunch of files in this folder: C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\java\vtk (C:\Program Files\CMake\bin is the place I built the binaries from Step 2. from the first link and Step 5. of the second link). However, this folder is blank for me.
I went and looked at the Visual Studio console window and saw this Error message:

```
298>CMake Error at Utilities/Java/cmake_install.cmake:45 (file):
298>  file INSTALL cannot find "C:/Program
298>  Files/CMake/bin/lib/Debug/vtkJava-9.0d.lib": No such file or directory.
298>Call Stack (most recent call first):
298>  cmake_install.cmake:416 (include)
298>
298>
298>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(153,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
298>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(153,5): error MSB3073: cmake.exe -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake
298>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(153,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
298>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(153,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
298>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(153,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
298>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(153,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
298>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(153,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
298>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(153,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
298>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(153,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
298>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(153,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
298>Done building project "INSTALL.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

So what happened here, in my eyes, is that build for INSTALL failed because, somehow, Visual Studio couldn't find 'C:\Program Files' because of the space? Going off this assumption, I looked up a few things (used this link:

> https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/solved-windows-cannot-find-cprogram-files/5b3fe4fc-5ade-4616-89ad-8d2fb4076be0

and pressed win+R and navigated to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options
```

and was advised to delete __.exe, with the __ being the thing that is causing the error. However, I couldn't find a 'cmake.exe' or 'visual studios.exe' or anything like that; I figured maybe it's listed as something else, but maybe I'm also just approaching this the wrong way.
Can someone help me with the error in building INSTALL?

I get the feeling that I may be missing a bunch of information or maybe I'm not explaining something. Please feel free to point this out and what more I need to include and I'll be happy to reword something or include some images. Thanks!

Comment: My advice is to not install to Program Files anyways. You can change the install location in cmake-gui at the configure step.

Comment: This may be caused above in the INSTALL. Remember that "C:\Program Files" is a protected path. You need UAC elevation to write there so even being an Administrator is not enough.

Comment: @drescherjm I moved the file to another folder and it seemed to fix that problem; I'm now faced with another unrelated problem but it seems like there's an answer to this problem elsewhere. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

One answer, as suggested by @drescherjm above, is to just change the install location that doesn't have a space in it. For example, I put it directly in the 'C:\Users[username]' folder; there are problems with not having permission to view/edit protected folders, but that shouldn't be a problem if you can simply run the program as an administrator (in my case, it's Visual Studios).